# Automatically filling in HTML form from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

Intended Outcome: Automatically fill out a form on load using `document.getElementById`, javascript only.

I have an array that passes into the following function, which correctly adds it to html script.

```
 function showResults(results) {
     var s = "";
     for (var i=0, il=results.features.length; i<il; i++) {
         var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;

         for (att in featureAttributes) {
             s = s + "<b>" + att + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[att] + "<br />";
             // var subshed = feature[0].attributes["SubWS"];

         }
     }
     dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = s;
 }
```

The outcome looks like

```
OBJECTID: 190
ProjectTyp: Stormwater Retrofit
Unit: Lower
SubWS: sadd
```

However, I need to modify the script to fill out an existing form with

```
document.getElementById(att).value = featureAttributes[att];
```

I always seem to overwrite the final output so I only fill in a single form value.  How do I go about filling out multiple values?

UPDATE: Mr. Polywhirl got it right.  I also had to add in an if statement to deal with null attribute values.  Final code was:

```
 function showResults(results) {
            var subshed = results.features[0].attributes["SubWS"];
            //OBJECTID = results.features[0].attributes["OBJECTID"];
document.getElementById("searchString").value = subshed;
                console.log("feature", results.features[0].attributes["SubWS"])
console.log(document.getElementById("Map_ID"));
        var s = "";
    for (var i = 0, il = results.features.length; i < il; i++) {
          var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
          for (att in featureAttributes) {
        // s = s + "<b>" + att + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[att] + "<br />";
  //         var subshed = feature[0].attributes["SubWS"];

                //    document.getElementById(att).value = featureAttributes[att];
  if(!!featureAttributes[att]&&!!document.getElementById(att)){
                    document.getElementById(att).value = featureAttributes[att];


}else{

//alert(att + "this is null")

}
          }

        }

     //   dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = s;
      }
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using?

Comment: Where is the att being asigned as the id?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/w6Zam/8/

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you have some heavily nested data source for your form.

I've made two examples for you parsing a JS object, which you can attain by useing the JSON.parse(jsonString) method supported in all recent browser whereas the old ones can use the JSON2.js polyfill freely available online.

In the first case I've used a MVx framework called angularJS to illustrate the use of such,

I've made it quite non-elegant, however its quite understandable for beginners.

Controller:

```
function FormData($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        OBJECTID: 190,
        ProjectTyp: "Stormwater Retrofit",
        Unit: "Lower",
        SubWS: "sadd"
    };
}
```

part of the view

```
<form action="path/to/your/action/svc" method="post" ng-controller="FormData">
    <div>
        <label>OBJECTID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="{{data.OBJECTID}}" />
    </div>
```

The second example on the same fiddle uses plain(vanilla) JS to populate a form transforming the JSON.parse(d) object into an array and mapping it into the form.

Object to array:

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
    var arr =[];
    for(x in obj) {
        arr.push(obj[x]);
    }
      return arr;
}

var dataArr = objectToArray(data);
```

population:

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
var formItems = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(x in formItems) {
    if(formItems[x].type == "text") {
         formItems[x].value = dataArr[x];
    }
}
```

the fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vqbM/1/)

Hope it helps,

Mike.